# (United States) Proof that you can get into a Master's program with a Bachelor's degree

Tags: masters, united-states, certification

I have finished my college studies and am graduating with a Bachelor of Science degree. I have thought about what would be my next step and decided to pursue a Master's degree abroad, namely in Spain. I am submitting my application to multiple Universities, and in a few, I came across a request for some sort of "certificate" that the Bachelor of Science, here in the United States qualifies you for a Master's degree.
I came across the following: "*Justificación de que el título aportado faculta, en el país expedidor del mismo, para el acceso a enseñanzas universitarias de posgrado.*" in a free translation that would be: "Proof that the title held by you, allows in the country it was expedited on, for access to a University Master program" or [in another university's wording](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u34p0.png).

Sounds simple enough right? Except for the fact that everyone I consulted in my university, ranging from advisors to college directors is unsure of where to get something like that, or even how that would look like.

Well, my question can be summarized into, is there some sort of institution in the United States (or Ohio, if this would be a state-level issue) that offers some sort of document saying "In the U.S., Bachelor's degrees work just fine for a Master's program admission"?

Thanks!

Comment: In general, I would expect you to need to get your degree "recognized," as described (in Spanish) [here](https://www.educacionyfp.gob.es/mc/convalidacion-homologacion/convalidacion-no-universitaria/solicitud.html). But this is probably not the answer to your question, since your quote asks for a "justificacion" of how things work "en el pais expedidor del mismo." Strange. Are you sure this has to be a "certificate" rather than just a paragraph that you write yourself?

Answer (score 5):

This is the sort of thing a university registrar should be able to do by providing a signed letter for you. If your GPA is especially low they might not want to provide the letter, but if your university also offers a masters they will have an idea about how to respond.

Even a department head could probably provide an acceptable letter.

I assume that the request is to account for the fact that terminology differs around the world and non standard degrees might be offered in some places.

You could also ask them directly what they would accept, providing a couple of examples such as the above.